# WooCommerce + Ionic: Unable to signup and checkout - Fetch API cannot load

Tags: wordpress, ionic-framework, woocommerce, cors, woocommerce-rest-api

I am working on a project that integrates WooCommerce with Ionic 3 and I am having problems with the signup and checkout functionality. I am able to read products and login from my WooCommerce site, but every time I do a post request, I am getting these errors:

> {"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"Invalid signature - provided signature does not match."}]}

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Just as the error is telling you: "Invalid signature - provided signature does not match."  You are not providing the correct signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the following code in your .htaccess file on the top. You can find this file in the root of your WordPress.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $l [R=200,L]
```

Also enable CORS on your browser.