# woocommerce rest api: can't get preflight request to pass

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce, cors

I have a woocommerce site and I want its REST API to be open to the world.

I have learned that CORS headers need to be set, so I google and setup the following hook:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function() {
remove_filter('rest_pre_serve_request', 'rest_send_cors_headers');   
add_filter('rest_pre_serve_request', function( $value ) {
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *' );
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE' );
    header( 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true' );
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Origin,Content-Type,X-Auth-Token,Content-Range,Range');
    return $value;
});
}, 15);
```

I confirmed that my server is responding with the correct CORS headers:

> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers:
>
> Authorization,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Origin,Content-Type,X-Auth-Token,Content-Range,Range
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods: OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>
> Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages

Then I headed to code the client side:

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://..../wp-json/wc/v3/products');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + btoa('mykey:mysecret'));
xhr.send(JSON.stirngify({ ... });
```

Above code was entered in Chrome console under a https://google.com tab. I just can't get the preflight request to work, here are the errors：

> OPTIONS https://..../wp-json/wc/v3/products 401 (Unauthorized)
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://..../wp-json/wc/v3/products' from origin
>   'https://www.google.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have
>   HTTP ok status.

Even though the response headers are exactly like posted above.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/44884623/441757. You need to add handling for OPTIONS requests, and that answer explains how to add that handling in your Apache config. I think it might be necessary to do it there — in the Apache config — rather than in your woocommerce/wordpress/php code

Answer (score 0):

if you are using: "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" = true make sure that "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is not "*", it must be set with a proper domain!